# Shortcut key to go to the method declaration?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am working on an application which is not developed by me so while understanding the code,I generally go to the method definition by using F12, then there are chances that in this method another method may be there, then i go to this method definition by using F12 so now my question is that how can I back to the starting method

method 1-Here i pressed F12

method 2-After Pressing F12 i am here, method 3 was also called here then i pressed F12 again

method 3-At last I am here

So how can i go back to the method 1 or method 2.

language: C#

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127547/keyboard-shortcut-to-move-cursor-between-methods-in-visual-studio

Comment: Dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147974/is-there-an-easy-way-to-jump-right-to-a-method-within-a-file

Comment: @PhilipPittle: Please (if you didn't) flag to close in these cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hard way**: bookmark where you are, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and back to your bookmark using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

**Easy way**: Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to backward and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to forward.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>   will navigate back to the previous code point.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> keys

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> is used to go back to the previous point.

you can visit [this](http://www.dofactory.com/ShortCutKeys/ShortCutKeys.aspx) for all the keyboard shortcuts in VS.