# Find method in current file/class in VS2015/C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, code-navigation

I can use the `Ctrl+,` shortcut to search for methods but will search among the entire project:

[image]

This lists all the classes in all files that have this method, and I want to search only in the current file, similar to `Alt+M` in VAssistX. Is there a shortcut for that?

I found [Is there an easy way to jump right to a method within a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147974/is-there-an-easy-way-to-jump-right-to-a-method-within-a-file), but it's for VS2012, and they only suggest `Ctrl+F` or `Ctrl+,`.

**Note:** I'm looking for true navigation, not `Ctrl+F`, and only within the current file, unlike `Ctrl+,`.

Comment: You can still use the `Ctrl` `,` search if you type the classname first and then use `.` i.e. `TextGridFilter.GetFilter` will only show the `GetFilter` method from `TextGridFilter`. Is that acceptable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To expand on the answer by Matt Schley:

Ctrl + F2 -> Tab -> then start typing and it'll sift through the functions in the file.

I know you were probably looking for something else, but this is as good as it gets for what's built into Visual Studio.  Maybe there's extensions available.

**EDIT**

This is a mapping for C#.  The command name is `Window.MovetoNavigation`

**For C++, it's default is Ctrl + F8**

Comment: `Ctrl+F2` sets a bookmark for me, but it's probably because I had Visual C++ 6 mapping scheme set in Environment.Keyboard. Can you tell me which keyboard command it is, so I can map a shortcut to it?

Comment: @sashoalm A person from this post said `Ctrl+F8` for C++ settings. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454642/is-there-a-hotkey-in-visual-studio-to-open-the-member-drop-down-list

Comment: @CrazyPaste Thanks, I figured it out. The navigation bar was missing from my VS2015, I had to reenable it - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1441255/492336. The hotkey was indeed `Ctrl+F8`.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but there is a dropdown menu right above the code editor window that lists all methods *and* properties in the current file.

Try  Ctrl + F2 to active the navigation bar, then tab over twice and you can scroll through the dropdown.

Answer (score 5):

For VS2019 you can use `Alt + \` for object search.

Answer (score 2):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/go-to?view=vs-2019, it says `Ctrl+1, Ctrl+M` for `Go to the specified member`. You can add your own combination to this command by going to Tools -> Options -> Keyboard and choosing `Edit.GoToMember`. For me it works just perfect.

[image]

Comment: I believe this feature is now ruined due to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-a-new-way-to-search-your-code-and-visual-studio-features/ . There is no longer a way to go to methods within a file, only all methods.